# How to get the address of a nearby square on a chess board?

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas, chess

I'm making a chess game from scratch and I got stuck.

So far I have all my figures placed, I have the positions set, I've already done the collision detection and everything.

When I click the figure that is in position A1 for example, I want to make two green rectangles at positions A2 and A3, and they will be used to make the figure move.

Is there a method for to add 1 to the string "A1" to form the string "A2" or something? Because thats all I really need right now.

Also if there's a more clever way to make the positions please let me know.

As an example, here is how I currently look up my display positions using the A1, A2 etc. location codes:

```
let positions = {
        A1 : [10, 710],B1 : [110, 710],C1 : [210, 710],D1 : [310, 710],E1 : [410, 710],F1 : [510, 710],G1 : [610, 710],H1 : [710, 710],
        A2 : [10, 610],B2 : [110, 610],C2 : [210, 610],D2 : [310, 610],E2 : [410, 610],F2 : [510, 610],G2 : [610, 610],H2 : [710, 610],
        A3 : [10, 510],B3 : [110, 510],C3 : [210, 510],D3 : [310, 510],E3 : [410, 510],F3 : [510, 510],G3 : [610, 510],H3 : [710, 510],
        A4 : [10, 410],B4 : [110, 410],C4 : [210, 410],D4 : [310, 410],E4 : [410, 410],F4 : [510, 410],G4 : [610, 410],H4 : [710, 410],
        A5 : [10, 310],B5 : [110, 310],C5 : [210, 310],D5 : [310, 310],E5 : [410, 310],F5 : [510, 310],G5 : [610, 310],H5 : [710, 310],
        A6 : [10, 210],B6 : [110, 210],C6 : [210, 210],D6 : [310, 210],E6 : [410, 210],F6 : [510, 210],G6 : [610, 210],H6 : [710, 210],
        A7 : [10, 110],B7 : [110, 110],C7 : [210, 110],D7 : [310, 110],E7 : [410, 110],F7 : [510, 110],G7 : [610, 110],H7 : [710, 110],
        A8 : [10, 10], B8 : [110, 10], C8 : [210, 10], D8 : [310, 10], E8 : [410, 10], F8 : [510, 10], G8 : [610, 10], H8 : [710, 10],
    }
```

the [0] of the arrays is x and the [1] is y, and that's also how I placed the figures.

Comment: Instead of strings have you considered using numbers? Top-left is square 0. Second from the left is square 1. Second from the top is square 8. And so on. Or coordinates: top-left: [0,0], second from the left: [1,0], second from the top: [0,1] and so on.

Comment: ye thats what im about to do , thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like what you really want is a 2D array for managing your board state, [which in JavaScript you can accomplish with a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/966225/3064164).

Your x & y coordinates stay as plain integers internally, so you can use them as indexes into the first/outer and second/inner dimensions of the array. This makes it easy to add and subtract coordinates, or [compute other useful spatial patterns, like potential knight moves](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/178314/39518).

You then convert to "A1" style chess notation for display only, rather than using it as your underlying model. For example, using internal `x, y` indices in the range 0...7:

```
siteToLabel = function(x, y) {
    // 65 is the ASCII code for capital A, and the
    // rest of the alphabet proceeds sequentially.
    return String.fromCharCode(65 + x) + (y + 1).toString();
}
```

You can similarly compute your display coordinates this way, without the lookup table you're using now:

```
siteToDisplayCoords = function(x, y) {
    return [10 + 100 * x, 710 - 100 * y];
}
```

Once you're using integer indices internally, it's trivial to navigate to adjacent sites: just add/subtract one from your x or y index.

Comment: thats so smart , i didnt think of that , thank you so much it will make my life so much easier !

Comment: I started making it and i didnt understand one thing , i did the 2d array and now im computing the old A1 as [0][0] , A2 as [0][1] ec. and thats ok if i have 1 number in it , but i need to have 2 , x and y , i didnt understand how ill that work ,  if the pawn is at [0][1] , how will the green things pop in [0][2] and [0][3] ? is there a way to add up to an index to become [0][1] from [0][0] for example?

Comment: If you need to store 2 variables in one entry of an array, you can always just nest the array one layer deeper: `positions[xIndex][yIndex] = [xValue, yValue]; xPosition = positions[xIndex][yIndex][0];` But you don't need to store positions in a table because the method shown above already lets you calculate your positions from x & y directly, no lookup table required.

Comment: I don't really understand what the functions you wrote in your main answer do , if you can break them down a bit for me it would be perfect , because i really want to learn .

Comment: The first takes an x, y coordinate pair for a square and produces the chess notation for it, like (0,0)→"A1", (1,3)→"B4", (7,7)→"H8". The second returns an array containing the x & y display positions for that square, replacing the `positions` map shown in your question.

Comment: sorry if im annoying you , but which one should i use or i should use both of them , because everything in my mind got really messed up :D

Comment: It depends what you want. Do you want to print the name of a square in chess notation? Then use the function that gives you that. Do you want to know where to position an element to line up with a particular square? Then use the function that gives you display coordinates. You might use both in different parts of your game, or you might never need one of them. I haven't seen your game nor your codebase apart from the single map you shared, so I can't tell you more about how to integrate this change.

Comment: ok i played around with your functions and understood what they are doing , its game changing and now i have a clear question , lets say my pawn is at position  coords(0,0) which is with your function , how , when i click this pawn to calculate the x and the y of the 2 green rectangles that i want to spawn in the 2 positions infront of the pawn so that the player can choose where to move it next.

Comment: If the pawn is at (x, y), then the two squares it can move to for its first move are (x, y+1) or (x, y+2) (or minus if it's coming from the other side of the board) assuming no captures are available.